# Is there an easy way to propose a new meeting location in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

If I receive a meeting request in Outlook, I have the options to accept/tentative accept/decline the meeting. Additionally, I can also propose a new *time*.

But is there also an easy way to **propose a new *location*** (apart from writing a mail to the meeting organizer)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't think that's possible at the moment, however you can up-vote for this functionality on the [Outlook Feedback website](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/13876989-option-to-propose-a-new-meeting-location-in-micros)